# Tstringlist vs. Tstrings in a procedure call

Tags: delphi

I want to use a Delphi library from a friend,  this lib contains several procedures like below with the tstrings class.

```
AStringsprocedure (param_lines : TStrings;  .....  others stuff) 
begin 
     ///  add some add lines eg. to a memo or ....
     param_lines.add ('some text'); 
     .....
end;
```

in the reference code these functions a called like

```
 AStringsprocedure (Outmemo.Lines, .... );
```

passing vcl gui components.

I want to use these functions but I need to pass a TStringlist class instead.
How to use this functions with a TStringlist, any cast or ... trick?

Comment: TStringList is a descendant of TStrings, so no cast is necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi, `TStringList` is defined as so:

```
TStringList = class(TStrings)
```

Meaning `TStringList` already is a `TStrings`. Components/controls expose such properties as a `TStrings` which is abstract, no actual implementation inside. `TStringList` on the other hand contains the actual implementation. Internally, they use `TStringList` to contain the actual data, but make it available via `TStrings`. For example, in the `TStrings`, `abstract` methods only describe the signatures...

```
procedure Insert(Index: Integer; const S: string); virtual; abstract;
```

And then `TStringList` actually implements them...

```
procedure Insert(Index: Integer; const S: string); override;
```

So long story short, you don't need to do any casting/converting - you can just implicitly pass your `TStringList` as is.

---

**Bonus**

Sometimes, you might see something like this...

```
var
  L: TStrings;
begin
  L:= TStringList.Create;
  ...
end;
```

`TStrings`, being the base class of `TStringList`, is only a placeholder for whatever implementation you might have. But when you actually create it, you tell it what implementation to use. In most cases, `TStringList` is used. But every now and then, you might find another class which inherits from `TStrings` and implements it. You could even write your own implementation too if you wanted to, and override the abstract methods to your needs.

Comment: FWIW, the TStrings exposed by e.g. VCL components are implemented as wrappers for the string storages of the Windows class that forms the base of the VCL component. So a TMemo has an internal TMemoStrings (or similar) which uses the Windows EDIT control in multiline mode, which is the underlying control for TMemo, to manipulate the strings. FMX usually doesn't rely on such OS-defined controls and therefore often uses TStringList directly.

Comment: @Rudy Indeed, one example of implementation other than the `TStringList`.